# DHTMLX Timeline tootip on y-axis

Tags: dhtmlx-scheduler

In the scheduler timelineview is there a way to put a tooltip on each row of an y-axis? In my case the y-axis is an abbreviation for a team and I need to show the firstname and lastname in the tooltip.

Comment: This works, thx

Answer (score 0):

Inbuilt Scheduler tooltip functionality which can be included by dhtmlxscheduler_tooltip.js extension works only for events.

To solve your issue, you can use [HTML title Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_title.asp) (as it said on the forum on a link that Phong Nguyen shared).

I also created a [demo](https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/e767ef199) for you so you can check how it works.